# Httpresponse redirect to class based view

Tags: python, django

For some reason I can not use django's default authentication system, for that I wrote custom login function. Now every success login I want my user redirect into another app class based view.

i.e:

```
#frontend/views.py
login(request, user)
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('platform:UserProfileView'))

#frontend/urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('frontend.views',
    url(r'^$', 'base_view', name='base_view'),
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'login_user', name='login_user')
)

#platform/urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('platform.views',
    url(r'^(?P<user>.+)$', UserProfileView.as_view(), name='user_profile_view'),
)
```

Now my above workaround given below error:

> Reverse for 'UserProfileView' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

```
#platform/vies.py

class UserProfileView(View):
    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def get(self, request, user):
        if request.user.username == user:
            profile = request.user
            return render(request, 'app/homepage.html', {'profile': profile})
        else:
            raise Http404
```

Am I missing something? or Any other way around this?

**Full Traceback:**

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/

Django Version: 1.7
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'frontend',
 'platform')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/vijay/nightybuild/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/vijay/nightybuild/readtamil/frontend/views.py" in login_user
  49.                 return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('UserProfileView', args=(user.username,)))
File "/home/vijay/nightybuild/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  546.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
File "/home/vijay/nightybuild/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  463.                              (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /accounts/login/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'UserProfileView' with arguments '(u'username',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined a name for the url. Use the name with appropriate argument.

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

...

login(request, user)
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('platform:user_profile_view',
                                    args=(user.username,)))

# OR

return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('platform:user_profile_view',
                                    kwargs={'user': user.username}))
```

NOTE: I assume the view accepts username as parameter. Change `args` accordingly.

Comment: Now the error is revers match with argument {u'username} ..... And also i updated my question with Class view .. tell me is username ok or else?

Comment: @iask, I don't understand your comment. If you mean you get an error, could you show the full traceback?

Comment: @iask, As I wrote in the answer, use the name of the url, not the class name: `reverse('UserProfileView', ...)` -> `reverse('user_profile_view', ...)`

Comment: still same .. i am gonna drop this idea .. Exception Value: Reverse for 'user_profile_view' with arguments '(u'simon',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Comment: @iask, Here are alternatives: `reverse('platform:user_profile_view', args=(user.username,))`,  `reverse('platform:user_profile_view', kwargs={'user': user.username})`

Comment: @iask, I updated the answer accordingly. Thank you for the feedbacks.