# Passing a parameter to a class based view from a redirect

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I have a class based view (`RegistrationView`) which I'd like to pass a parameter value to upon redirect, as per the following.

```
# views.py
def hook(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('registration_register',
                                    kwargs={'initial': {'email': 'user@example.com'}}))
```

Where my accompanying URL pattern for this is defined as:

```
# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^account/register/$',
        RegistrationView.as_view(form_class=RegistrationForm), 
        name='registration_register'),
]
```

And *initial* is a valid parameter value in `RegistrationView`.

However, when I run this, I hit the following error, as I have not defined the argument in my urls (and I don't want to have to define the parameter in the url path if possible).

> Reverse for 'registration_register' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'initial': {'email': 'user@example.com'}}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['account/register/$']

I came across the following [query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25947125/httpreponse-redirect-to-class-based-view) which discusses passing keyword arguments to class based views, however, I have not been able to get it to work with the above code.

Conceptually what I am trying to achieve is the equivalent of the below, except using a `HttpRedirect` instead of generating a straight response.

```
def hook(request):
    return RegistrationView.as_view(
         form_class=RegistrationForm, initial={'email': 'user@example.com'})(request)
```

Is anyone able to advise how I can redirect to my view with this *initial* parameter value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing up a few things.

The parameters you pass to `reverse` with `args` and `kwargs` are used to build a URL. For a view to accept these arguments, the corresponding URL pattern has to have a placeholder for it.

Have a look at this example:

```
# urls.py
...
url(r'^/polls/(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
...

# views.py
def detail(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're looking at question %s." % question_id)

>>> reverse('detail', kwargs={'question_id': 123})
'/polls/123/'
```

If you want to pass any extra information, you can use query paramters, e.g.

`/polls/123/?foo=bar`

`reverse` is only responsible for the path portion of the URL, i.e until the `?`, you have to build the whole this manually.

```
django.utils.http import urlencode
path = reverse('detail', kwargs={'question_id': 123})
params = urlencode({'foo': 'bar'})
url = "%s?%s" % (path, params)
```

You can access query parameters in your view with `request.GET`, in this example `request.GET.get('foo')`.

Now, regarding your class based view. Simply speaking, `as_view()` is the wrong place to look to pass arguments that should be different for each request. Under the hood, the expression `RegistrationView.as_view(form_class=RegistrationForm)` creates a factory function, which instantiates a new RegistrationView instance for every request. `as_view()` "stores" its arguments and passes them to `RegistrationView.__init__()`.

**TL;DR:**

Pass the email as query parameter, like the parameter `next` in the login URL.

```
/account/register/?email=user@example.com
```

If your `RegistrationView` is a standard `FormView`, you can overwrite `get_initial` to fetch the parameter.

```
def get_initial(self):
    initial = super(RegistrationView, self).get_initial()
    email = self.request.GET.get('email')
    if email is not None:
        initial['email'] = email
    return initial
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, as you say, you haven't defined that parameter in your URL, so I don't know what you think the reverse function is going to do with it. Despite what you say about it being a "valid parameter" for RegistrationView, it's clear that that view doesn't expect that parameter either.

If you want to pass this data via `reverse`, you need to write a view that does expect parameters, and give it a URL that accepts those parameters.

An alternative might be to pass this data using the session.

Comment: Excellent - session does what I require in this instance, as I don't need to pass the email via the query string.